# windows server 2003 driver

Tags: windows-server-2003

OK, my CPU is 64 bit bt also supports 32bit software. So I've installed Windows Server 2003 on my PC. But here's my problem:I could install all the drivers but no driver is recognized except for the vdeo driver.No sound, no usb no nothing. What could the problem be?
The Server is 32 bit.

Comment: FYI 32bit drivers are an exception; on a 64bit version of windows 64bit drivers are mandatory

Comment: Have you installed 32bit or 64bit Windows Server 2003 (x86/x64?)

Comment: I installed 32 bit version of Windows 2003 server.

Comment: to update your question, associate your Stack Overflow and Super User accounts, then use the `edit` link to add info to your question. The best option would be to [log in](http://superuser.com/users/login) on both sites so that your account is permanently registered, then you will have access to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically put, if your processor support x64/64-bit, you can use either a x64/64 bit operating system or an x86/32-bit operating system.

The drivers you download **have** to match the operating system.

Next, depending on both the age and type of the machine, you may not be able to get all the drivers. Simply put, the way Windows Server works underneath is slightly different to the normal desktop Windows and because of this, some drivers just are not compatible.

You can however try to download Windows XP drivers (As the XP <-> 2003 kernel is similar) but not everything will work.

Lastly, when you do have the sound and other drivers installed, you will need to go to services and enable the Windows Audio service. There are many services on a server that are disabled by default that you would want when using as a desktop - however, if you are actually using this as a server, there is no need to have sound and I would actually recommend disabling it in the BIOS.